# Consulta campo no firebase retornando null

Tags: android, query, firebase-database

Estou realizando a busca pelo campo (valor) na tabela (receita) na base de dados do firebase, porém ao realizar o debug obtenho o seguinte:

```
V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@cf4b4d9 nm : **com.example.controlefinanceiro ic=null**
D/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - Id : 0
I/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=93
    Input channel destroyed: fd=89
```

No campo aparece "null", segue a estrutura do meu banco [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
private void inicializaComponentes() {
.... 
mDatabaseRefence = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
mDatabaseRefence.child("receita").child("valor").addValueEventListener( new ValueEventListener() { 
@Override public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) { txtValor_Inicial = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtValor_Inicial); txtValor_Inicial.setText(String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue())); }
```

Comment: Qual a consulta ? copia e cole o código da sua consulta, temos que saber como você fez

Comment: @JoanMarcos adicionei o código

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiz da seguinte forma:

```
mDatabaseRefence = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
mDatabaseRefence.child("Receita").child("21420329-7525-475b-aec7-ac6ec037183b").child("valor").addValueEventListener( new ValueEventListener()...
```

Encontrei a solução neste link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43293935/how-to-get-child-of-child-value-from-firebase-in-android